# Getting a 404 using a php / HTML shrotcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, http-status-code-404

On a Wordpress page I use only a shortcode with the following PHP code with inserted HTML:

[Code mit PHP und HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhk7s.png)

The code is running correctly. When I insert the two line (see picture) I get a 404 message. The URL is shown correctly. When I click on the Edit page the page which should be invoked by the action is shown.

I have similar effects with other pages? What do I make wrong???

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple when you see it.

The use of name in the name="" attribute is not allowed (like some others).